# WCF RIA Services Forms Authentification using authcookies from another subdomain

Tags: wcf, silverlight, cookies, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I am trying to develop a Single Sign On across several .net applications. One of them is WFC RIA service. I changed webconfig of the service to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".Auth" loginUrl="http://anotherdomain.com/LoginPage" defaultUrl="/" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" domain=".domain.com">
</forms>
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="mykey" decryptionKey="anotherkey" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

When the silverlight app starts it makes a call to the service to retrieve a version and during and Auth cookies are set.

```
POST http://sub.domain.com/ClientBin/Service.svc/binary/GetVersion HTTP/1.1
Host: sub.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
content-type: application/msbin1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=jcdt25iao3l0tfkq14jolc3u; .Auth=19025717979A72FCE9CA09CC29F958398D7EC2C4EAD735638A88BC1FE195B9D88D6785062D5D71801CE50EBCDDF6F40189865BBAD8A089BBF22BBE28D51F5AD4CDE654B6CBFD107D37791C4DB69C9D850683A64A69D81E135335678D32CD757C5BB37D0CBC2D886B0FF3CFE09F587B2C2F60608D49989B4FD6F2726F99443651DD3C27C0
```

But when the app tries to call    WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser    calls GetUser() method from the service the cookies are empty and I can not get the user name to return a user coorectly.

```
GET http://sub.domain.com/ClientBin/AuthService.svc/binary/GetUser HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Referer: http://sub.domain.com/ClientBin/AppName.xap?ver=0.1.1.1&bt=635539986677594087
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Host: sub.domain.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```